# how to identify the minimal set of parameters describing a data set

Tags: algorithm

I have a bunch of regression test data.  Each test is just a list of messages (associative arrays), mapping message field names to values.  There's a lot of repetition within this data.

For example

```
   test1 = [
      { sender => 'client',  msg => '123',  arg => '900', foo => 'bar', ... },
      { sender => 'server',  msg => '456',  arg => '800', foo => 'bar', ... },
      { sender => 'client',  msg => '789',  arg => '900', foo => 'bar', ... },
   ]
```

I would like to represent the field data (as a minimal-depth decision tree?) so that each message can be programatically regenerated using a minimal number of parameters.  For example, in the above

- foo is always 'bar', so I don't need to mention it
- sender and client are correlated, so I only need to mention one or the other
- and msg is different each time

So I would like to be able to regenerate these messages with a program along the lines of

```
write_msg( 'client', '123' )
write_msg( 'server', '456' )
write_msg( 'client', '789' )
```

where the write_msg function would be composed of nested if statements or subfunction calls using the parameters.

Based on my original data, how can I determine the 'most important' set of parameters, i.e. the ones that will let me recreate my data set using the smallest number of arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following papers describe algortithms for discovering functional dependencies:

> Y. Huhtala, J. Kärkkäinen, P. Porkka,
>   and H. Toivonen.  TANE: An efficient
>   algorithm for discovering functional 
>   and approximate dependencies. *The
>   Computer Journal*,  42(2):100–111,
>   1999, [doi:10.1093/comjnl/42.2.100](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/comjnl/42.2.100).
>
> I. Savnik and P. A. Flach. Bottom-up
>   induction of functional  dependencies
>   from relations. In Proc. *AAAI-93 Workshop:
>   Knowledge Discovery in Databases*,
>   pages 174–185, Washington,  DC, USA,
>   1993.
>
> C. Wyss, C. Giannella, and E.
>   Robertson. FastFDs: A 
>   Heuristic-Driven, Depth-First
>   Algorithm for Mining Functional
>   Dependencies from Relation Instances.
>   In *Proc. Data Warehousing and Knowledge Discovery*, pages 101–110, Munich,
>   Germany, 2001, [doi:10.1007/3-540-44801-2](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/3-540-44801-2).
>
> Hong Yao and Howard J. Hamilton. "Mining functional dependencies from data."  *Data Mining and Knowledge Discovery*, 2008, [doi:10.1007/s10618-007-0083-9](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10618-007-0083-9).

There has also been some work on discovering multivalued dependencies:

> I. Savnik and P. A. Flach. "Discovery
>   of Mutlivalued Dependencies from
>   Relations." *Intelligent Data Analysis
>   Journal*, 4(3):195–211, [IOS Press](http://iospress.metapress.com/content/18wpfh7nvxqjamnm/), 2000.

Comment: Hmm.  I'm glad to see this problem really is hard, and I haven't been flailing around for no reason.  Thanks for collecting those references.

Answer (score 1):

This looks very similar to [Database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

You have a relation (your test data set), and some known functional dependencies ({sender} => arg, {} => foo and possibly {msg} => sender.  If the order of tests is important then add {testNr} => msg.) and you want to eliminate redundancies.

Treat your test set as a database table, apply the normalization rules and create equivalent functions (getArgFromSender(sender) etc.) for each join.

Answer (score 1):

**If the number of fields and records is small:**

Brute force it by looping through every combination of fields, and for each combination detect if there are multiple items in the list which map to the same value.

**If you can live with a fairly good choice of fields:**

Start off assuming you need all fields. Then, select a field at random and see if it can be eliminated; if it can, cross it off the set of fields. Otherwise, choose another field at random and try again. If you find no fields can be eliminated, then you've found a reasonable set of fields. Had you chosen other fields first, you may find a better solution. You can repeat the whole procedure a few times and pick the best solution if you like. This kind of approach is called [hill climbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing).

(I suspect that this problem is [NP complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete), i.e. we probably don't know of an efficient and powerful solution so it is not worth losing sleep over trying to dream up a perfect solution.)